# jquery on click function toggle class and function

Tags: jquery, click, toggle

here a play and pause button function

```
  $('#control').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass('play')) { // on first click, detect by if hasClass
      $this.removeClass('play').addClass('pause'); // maybe toggle class better
      $play_function(); // but here a function...
    } else {
      $this.removeClass('pause').addClass('play'); // maybe toggle class better
      $pause_function(); // but here a function too...
    }
  });
```

maybe toggle class is better, but a function ( $play_function() and $pause_function() ) inside, i need set default play or pause, so set a if...hasClass to detect the first on click, can have a simply way to toggle class and function by if `($this.hasClass('play')) or  if ($this.hasClass('pause'))`? or other method do this function?

above code work but a bit complex, i want to know any other simply method :)

thanks so much

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for a code review. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww Code Review would indeed be a better place to ask - but please note being on-topic elsewhere doesn't make a question off-topic here.

Comment: sorry about that, i will remember next time :) thanks you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you said, i would try the toggleClass function:

```
$('#control').on('click', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass("pause",function(){
        ($this.hasClass('pause')) ? pauseFunction():playFunction();
    });
});
```

Comment: in my code, add $this.toggleClass("pause play"), work perfect, thanks so much :)

Answer (score 2):

In html, add addition attribute as a tag as below

```
<button id="control" data-is-playing=0 ></button>
```

In script:

```
    var callFuncs = new Array();
    callFuncs[0] = function playFunction() {};// call play when paused
    callFuncs[1] = function pauseFunction() {};
    $('#control').on('click', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var stat = 1 - $this.attr("data-is-playing"); // maybe you can use  = ! $this.attr("data-is-playing"), I'm not sure
        $this.toggleClass('play'); // initially, there is no 'play'
        $this.attr("data-is-playing", stat);
        callFuncs[stat]();
    });
```

but @CodeGodie's solution seems much better with a little fault!

```
$('#control').on('click', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass("pause",function(){
     ($this.hasClass('pause')) ? pauseFunction():playFunction();
    }());// pay attention here
});
```

have fun!

Comment: thanks for html data solution, i learn from this answer,  and about the @CodeGodie solution, add () effect is? thanks you :)

Comment: In CodeGodie’s code, pauseFunction or playFunction  was not called when clicking the button when I test the code. 
After searching http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/, I thought he might mean calling “.toggleClass(className, state)”. So let ‘state’ be the returned value of function A in which we call pauseFunction or playFunction, I got those functions called as code “toggle(className, A())”. But actually A() return ‘undefined’ , the logic may be “jQuery seems omit the undefined param and only called ‘.toggleClass(className)’ “

Comment: @aboutjquery , using jquery 1.11.1

Comment: oh my god!!! yesterday i test the CodeGodie solution, its work, today, just now i test the code on other function, the function after toggleClass not run, anything after toggleClass not run, and i remember your answer, add the () to the code, its work now!!! wow, thanks so much, both of code using jquery 1.11.2, i dont knwo why one of my function not work without (), code is same, anyway, i will remember this hints:) thanks you

Answer (score 1):

Try

```js
var controls = {
    "play": function play(elem) {
      $(elem).css("color", "red")
    }, 

    "pause": function play(elem) {
      $(elem).css("color", "green")
  }
};  

$("#control").on("click", controls, function(e) {  
   return $(this).attr("class", function(i, c) {
     return c === "play" ? "pause" : "play"
   }) && controls[this.className](this)
});
```

```css
#control {
  font-size:36px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="control">click</div>
```

Comment: thanks again :) more info i want to know, play(elem), what is the elem meaning? thanks

Comment: @aboutjquery `elem` is `this` `#control` element , passed to `control.play`, `control.pause` as `argument` ; though could pass another element , or no element , depending on what expected return value of `control.play`, `control.pause` are . Utilized `#control` above as no context, or element, appear for `$play_function()` , `$plause_function()` at OP .